# Django-filters resets after using the UpdateView

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-filter, django-filters

I have a Model with a lot of entries, so I'm using django-filters to filter the model, I initially load an empty table and from there I use the filter to view the items.

Everything works fine, the page loads initially with no entry, after I filter, django shows the correct items.
The Url gets a parameter: `/retetabloc/?acordcadru=532`(532 is the filter) but when I try to update an entry, the filter resets(the parameter is still in the URL) and the whole db is loaded.

I don't quite understand how to pass the filter parameter to the `RetetaBlocUpdate`, so that after the update is done it returns to the filtered items like in the ListView.

views.py

```
class RetetaBlocListview(LoginRequiredMixin, CoreListView):
    model = RetetaBloc       
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pdb.set_trace()
        acordcadru = self.request.GET.get("acordcadru")
        queryset = RetetaBloc.objects.filter(acordcadru=acordcadru)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = RetetaBlocFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        pdb.set_trace()
        return context
```

```
class RetetaBlocUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, AjaxUpdateView):
    model = RetetaBloc
    form_class = RetetaBlocForm
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like filters to be remembered you could add them to a session variable instead.  That way filters would be recalled even if they didn't go back directly from the update page (and you'd wouldn't have redundant URL querystring on pages where they weren't needed).
Something like:

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    pdb.set_trace()
    #check for new filter in URL first
    acordcadru = self.request.GET.get("acordcadru")
    #if nothing check for session variable
    if not acordcadru:
        acordcadru = self.request.session.get('acordcadru')
    #if something in URL querystring, set it in session variable
    else:
         self.request.session['acordcadru'] = acordcadru
    queryset = RetetaBloc.objects.filter(acordcadru=acordcadru)
    return queryset
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, when I click on the Update button(so that the modal window shows i have this error in the terminal "Not Found: /retetabloc/update/1591/" also i've tried to debug the code that you gave me and variable acordcadru returns empty.

Comment: I corrected my spelling of 'acordcadru' in a couple of places which may help. The Not Found error looks like a separate issue - what is in your urls.py for RetetaBlocUpdate?

Comment: this is the urls.py for retetablocview and retetablocupdate : `path('retetabloc/', RetetaBlocListview.as_view(), name='retetabloc-list'),    
    path('retetabloc/update/<int:pk>/', RetetaBlocUpdate.as_view(), name='retetabloc-update'), `

Comment: That looks OK. The Not Found is trying to follow a link to a PK that doesn't exist in the database. Is there anything else to the updateview?  Are you returning a success URL perhaps?

Comment: Well, the PK exists in the database.

Comment: is AjaxUpdateView from django-fm, django formalizr or something else?

Comment: https://github.com/egursu/django-modal-ajax-crud , i've been using this git repo, cms has the AjaxUpdateView

Comment: Digging to that repo - there is a get_success_url() function in the mixins.  I've suggested a method to override (untested) in my answer.

Comment: the ```def get_queryset()``` overrides the  ```get_succes_url()```?

Comment: No, RetetaBlocUpdate has a default get_success_url(), which it inherits from mixins in AjaxUpdateView. That may be creating a call to your page without the querystring